# Background color property for div

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I need to add background color for a content div in home page of a website. Width of main div is 980px, content div is inside main div. Website design is something like below image. I tried to use background image, but its position is changing based on the screen resolution, and also i need this design only on home page. Any suggestion?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="main" style="width:980px; margin: 0 auto;">
<div id="header"><!--div content here--></div>
<div id="des"><!--contents in between header and footer--></div>
<div id="footer"> Footer content here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For eg 'wave' shaped image on the top, i used it as background image of header. below is the style for header div. But i can see the wave image only inside the main div.

```
<style>
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    background-image: url(../../image/header_line.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried? basically, if this orange div is inside the main div you need to either set `position absolute;` and set the desired width or use the new width measurement units `width: 100vw;`

Comment: You'll also want to set `left: 0px` to make sure it goes all the way to the left edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this piece of code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer-container blue">
    <div class="main-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer-container green">
    <div class="main-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer-container red">
    <div class="main-container"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer-container{width: 100%;}
.outer-container .main-container{width: 980px;margin: 0 auto;height: 100px;}
.blue .main-container{background: blue;}
.green .main-container{background: green;}
.red .main-container{background: red;}
```

Refer to this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62p7rzp8/)

Comment: In the fiddle it will be displaying in stretched way since it is lesser than 980px. But it will be displayed properly in the bigger screen

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content_div"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:#000;
position:relative;
margin-left:100px;
margin-top:60px;}

.content_div{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
height:60px;
width:100%;
background-color:#f00;
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Try [Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/y4h6Ldx7/)

Comment: If this works, great. You should still try to explain why this works, what you changed etc.. It makes the answer more useful